# stdout stream changes order after redirection?

Tags: c, io-redirection

These days I was learning the "apue", a result of an typical case confused me. The following are the sample codes of "sample.c":

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFF_SZ 4096

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    char buff[BUFF_SZ] = {'\0'};
    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SZ)) > 0) {
        printf("read %d bytes\n", n);
        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, n) != n) {
            err_sys("write error");
        }
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        err_sys("read error");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After compilation `gcc sample.c`, you can use this command `echo Hello | ./a.out` and get the following std output on terminal:

> read 6 bytes
> Hello

However, if you *redirect* the output to a file `echo Hello | ./a.out > outfile`, then use `cat outfile` to see the content:

> Hello
> read 6 bytes

The ouput changes order after *redirection*! I wonder if some one could tell me the reason?

Comment: Do not mix stdio with POSIX read/write on the same file. Result will be unpredictable, as you've just found out the hard way. If you absolutely have to, flush each time you switch from stdio to posix and back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the standard I/O function `printf`, when you output to a terminal, the standard output is by default line buffered.

```
printf("read %d bytes\n", n);
```

`\n` here cause the output to flush.

However, when you output to a file, it's by default fully buffered. The output won't flush unless the buffer is full, or you explicitly flush it.

---

The low level system call `write`, on the other hand, is unbuffered.

In general, intermixing standard I/O calls with system calls is not advised.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()`, by default, buffers its output, while `write()` does not, and there is no synchronisation between then.

So, in your code, it is possible that `printf()` stores its data in a buffer and returns, then `write()` is called, and - as `main()` returns, `printf()`s buffer is flushed so that buffered output appears.   From your description, that is happening when output is redirected.

It is also possible that `printf()` writes data immediately, then `write()` is called.   From your description, that happens when output is not redirected.

Typically, one part of redirection of a stream is changing the buffer - and therefore the behaviour when buffering - for streams like `stdout` and `stdin`.  The precise change depends on what type of redirection is happening (e.g. to a file, to a pipe, to a different display device, etc).

Imagine that `printf()` writes data to a buffer and, when flushing that buffer, uses `write()` to produce output.   That means all overt calls of `write()` will have their output produced immediately, but data that is buffered may be printed out of order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the writes are handled by `write(2)` call, so you effectively lose control of what happens. 
If we look at the documentation for [write(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) we can see that the writes are not guaranteed to be actually written until a `read()` occurs. More specifically:

```
A successful return from write() does not make any guarantee that data has 
been committed to disk. In fact, on some buggy implementations, it does not even 
guarantee that space has successfully been reserved for the data. The only way to 
be sure is to call fsync(2) after you are done writing all your data.
```

This means that depending on the implementation and buffering of the `write(2)` (which may differ even between redirects and printing to screen), you can get different results.

Comment: This quote has nothing to do whatsoever with the observed results.

Comment: We can gather from it that the write may not necessarily be handled the same way and not necessarily in the correct order depending on the implementation of the system call.

Comment: You are mistaken. This quote doesn't say that. `write` that delivers results out of order is worse than useless. Why would anyone ever think of specifying such a thing? What this quote is talking about is the situation when you call `write`, it returns, and then your OS crashes or the computer is turned off. In this case your data is not guaranteed to be preserved on disk. Moreover, data that is written at time T may end up on the disk and data that is written at time T-1 may not. It is not. repeat, not about both pieces of data ending up on the disk but with their order reversed in the file.